# How to cast back to multidimensional?

Tags: c, gcc, multidimensional-array, casting

How to cast back from `void*` ?

```
int *a[13][12];
void *b
int *c[13][12];

b = (void*) a;
c = (?????) b;
```

This

```
c = (int *[13][12])b;
```

says `cast specifies array type`

This

```
c = (int *[][])b;
```

says `array type has incomplete element type`.

Compiler is `gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1)`

Comment: c is an array not a pointer. if you declare c as int ***c then a normal cast will work.

Comment: @cegfault: that gives the error: "array type 'int *[13][12]' is not assignable"

Comment: for `int***` it says `incompatible types`

Comment: @cegfault If you do it, it will cegfault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, you cannot [assign to an array](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/arrayassign.html), so since c is declared as an array of arrays of pointers to ints, you can't assign it directly.

You could however overwrite all of its items by assigning c[i][j] in turn inside a for loop, for example.

Comment: `c` is not an array, `c` is a pointer to 2d arrays. Although I wanted it be so. Was am wrong?

Comment: @Dims: `c` is a 2D array of pointers, not a pointer to 2D arrays.

Answer (score 1):

c and a are arrays not pointers, see above, you can use a pointer to a (2 dim) array like

```
int a[13][12] ={ 1,2,3 };
void *b = &a;
int (*c)[13][12] = b;
```

and all that without casts

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign directly to an array, or cast to an array type in C. However, since arrays decay to pointers, you can copy the data from a `void *` pointer (i.e.: `memcpy`) to an array and use it as an array, e.g.:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int a1=1, a2=2, a3=3, a4=4;

    int *a[2][2] = { { &a1, &a2 }, { &a3, &a4 } };
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n", *a[0][0], *a[0][1], *a[1][0], *a[1][1]);

    void *b;
    b = (void*) a;

    int *c[2][2];
    memcpy(c, b, sizeof(c));
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n", *c[0][0], *c[0][1], *c[1][0], *c[1][1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling and running the following program will give you:

```
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
```

However, `c` and `a` are two different arrays now.